# How to let the character in a table stay at the top

Tags: html, css, html-table

Look at this code:

```
<table width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td  style="width:20%;"><span>hello world</span></td>
            <td  style="width:60%;">
                <textarea style="width:100%;height:200px;"></textarea>
             </td>
             <td>
             </td>
         </tr>    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The "hello world" in the left `<td>`

just stays at the middle (sometimes even at the bottom),

so what attribute should I set to let the word stay at the top of the table?
[Here is an online example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxayM/)

Comment: just add valign="top" to the td which have the hello world

Answer (score 1):

Just add `vertical-align: top;` to the td style.

[See it here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxayM/2/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<table width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td  style="width:20%;" valign="top"><span>hello world</span></td>
                    <td  style="width:60%;">
                        <textarea style="width:100%;height:200px;"></textarea>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```